# How to run headless Chrome in Gitlab

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Java integration test suite that I need to run as part of a Gitlab CI process. The integration test uses Selenium webdriver against the Chrome browser. I'm new to Gitlab CI, and can't seem to find a solution to running my tests on a headless Chrome browser inside of the Gitlab environment.

I know I need to tweak or add something inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` but don't know what to add.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update:**

**Scenario 1**: When I add the following script to `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
services:
- selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
variables:
    selenium_remote_url: "http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub/"
```

My gitlab CI process errors out with the following exception:

[image]

**Scenario 2**: When I add the following script to `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq & apt-get install wget
  - wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alonisser/11192482/raw/e1d8d4ed579d64902e951e4f9fa487b793035f9b/setup-headless-selenium-xvfb.sh
  - sh setup-headless-selenium-xvfb.sh
  - /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_1.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :1 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x16
  - export DISPLAY=:1
  - sleep 3
```

My gitlab CI process errors out with the following exception:
[image]

My integration test contains the following in the `@BeforeClass` method (i.e. the starting point of the test execution)

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeScenario() {


    ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();

    try {
        File chromeDriver = new File("src/test/resources/drivers");
        String driverPath = chromeDriver.getPath() + "/chromedriver";       

        chromeDriver = new File(driverPath);

        if (chromeDriver != null && !chromeDriver.canExecute()) {
            System.out.println("Setting driver as executable");
            chromeDriver.setExecutable(true);
        }
        if (chromeDriver != null && !chromeDriver.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("Setting driver as readable");
            chromeDriver.setReadable(true);
        }


        opts.addArguments("--headless");
        opts.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        opts.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        opts.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");  


        ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", ":1"))
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File(System.getenv("webdriver.chrome.driver")))
                .build();

        service.start();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(service, opts);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

In **Scenario 1** I use the following java line to get the env param

```
.usingDriverExecutable(new File(System.getenv("selenium_remote_url")))
```

Comment: @jnns, you should put your comment as an answer. This is probably orphaned, but would be nice for the asker to have a chance to say it worked or it didn't.

Comment: @Mystic Thank you. I have added a potential answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Docker image `selenium/standalone-chrome` you should have a full working Selenium installation that you can point your test suite to. No need for a hub URL because you're not running a set of Selenium nodes. The apt installation probably fails because you're not using a Debian based image for your CI.

---

[@Mystic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132504) suggested posting a previous comment of mine as an answer so it can be a potential answer. Here it is.